# .net ADAL Acquire Token for application without a user

Tags: c#, .net, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to acquire a token for the application without having a current user.  I'm getting an error message:

e.Message = "Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken"

Below is code I'm using to get the token.

```
ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantId);
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceID, clientId);

return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

My version is:

Can someone please help with this I've been trying for days... I can get a token just find when getting one for the current user but when I have background process such as sending an email from the application without an authenticated user I can't get a token.

Security setup under my app registration for Microsoft Graph "Application - Send Email from Any User"  But I don't think it is ever getting that far.  Security on Windows Azure AD is Delegated - Sign in and read user profile.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry didn't realize until after posts that version didn't paste:  Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory is version 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the token portion.  So for anyone else who is looking for this google creating an X509 Certificate and adding it to your Azure Manifest.  Then you can use the x509 cert to create a ClientAssertionCertificate.  Then use the clientassertion in a call to AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync.  This seems to work.  I can create a graphServiceClient.  However when I try to send the email I get a permission error:

The user account which was used to submit this request does not have the right to send mail on behalf of the specified sending account., Cannot submit message.

Despite having Permission Application - Send Mail as any user.  Anyone have any ideas?